# Select rows by values in a csv in R and save them in a new csv file

Tags: r, csv, select, bigdata, libreoffice-calc

I need to select some values from a big csv file and to save them in a new one using R. For example, the original table is this:

```
CODINV2   INCY  APPLID
701       BE    15831845
3103      DE    17301283 
701       BE    16428865
7802      NL    16285035
8501      IT    15725319
8502      IT    16428857
```

I would like to select only rows with INCY's values "BE" and "IT".
The new file csv should be like this:

```
CODINV2   INCY  APPLID
701       BE    15831845
701       BE    16428865
8501      IT    15725319
8502      IT    16428857
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe `dplyr` package would help? Try this:

```
library("dplyr")

data %>%
    filter(INCY %in% c("BE", "IT")) -> new_data
```

And just save new_data.

Answer (score 4):

We can try `%in%`

```
subset(df1, INCY %in% c('BE', 'IT'))
#    CODINV2 INCY   APPLID
#1     701   BE 15831845
#3     701   BE 16428865
#5    8501   IT 15725319
#6    8502   IT 16428857
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1, key='INCY')[c('BE', 'IT')]
```

Comment: How can I save the results in a new file?

Comment: @Marta Thanks for he comments and plus one for your `dplyr` method.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very basic question. I tested different approaches with relative large dataset.

`dplyr` is the fastest. `%in%` + `subset` is most slow.

```
text1 <- "
CODINV2   INCY  APPLID
701       BE    15831845
3103      DE    17301283 
701       BE    16428865
7802      NL    16285035
8501      IT    15725319
8502      IT    16428857"

df <- read.table(text=text1, head=T, as.is=T)
df1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:10000, function(x)df))

library(dplyr)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  akrun = subset(df1, INCY %in% c('BE', 'IT')),
  venyao = df1[df1$INCY=="BE"|df1$INCY=="IT", ],
  me = df1[df1$INCY %in% c("BE", "IT"), ],
  marta = df1 %>% filter(INCY %in% c("BE", "IT")),
  times = 10
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#   akrun 5.480150 5.609124 6.396097 5.741517 7.560138 7.757532    10   c
#  venyao 5.209888 5.308072 5.873945 5.401295 5.711413 7.893688    10  bc
#      me 4.769260 4.872918 5.331644 4.910891 5.179100 7.097614    10  b 
#   marta 2.422432 2.563379 2.643739 2.611616 2.766588 2.866825    10 a
```

**UPDATE:**

**include `data.table` in the comparison. `data.table` is fastest in any condition. I'm confused that `dplyr` is now the most slow approach.**

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  akrun = subset(df1, INCY %in% c('BE', 'IT')),
  venyao = df1[df1$INCY=="BE"|df1$INCY=="IT", ],
  me = df1[df1$INCY %in% c("BE", "IT"), ],
  marta = df1 %>% filter(INCY %in% c("BE", "IT")),
  akrun2 = setDT(df1, key='INCY')[c('BE', 'IT')],
  times = 10
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval  cld
#   akrun 3.154533 3.171639 3.825090 3.402216 3.641688 5.915990    10   c 
#  venyao 2.677642 2.761456 3.087618 2.772061 2.969455 5.485966    10  bc 
#      me 2.388564 2.428248 2.571111 2.505905 2.757010 2.884614    10 ab  
#   marta 5.026180 5.081942 5.455929 5.208863 5.466808 7.373691    10    d
#  akrun2 1.836410 1.919541 1.964562 1.955804 1.985567 2.213408    10 a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `read.csv.sql`:

```
library(sqldf)
read.csv.sql("file.csv", sql = "select * from file where INCY IN ('BE', 'IT')")
```

Though this is unlikely to be faster than using `readr` or `fread` to load the full table, then subsetting in R.